# Is there a way to join an open path to a closed one?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, anchor-point

I'm trying to connect the anchor of an oppen path to a closed path, is this doable?
I would assume paths had the ability to fork.

Comment: Close the open path and weld both objects together. If you just want the line, convert the stroke to outlines then weld them.

Answer (score 1):

Paths don't fork. the best thing to do is make another layer and group the objects, or outline paths and join them all. I'm not sure what else to say with out more specifics of your current project.